# AWS IoT SQL Query does not populate "state" in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I'm encountering an issue with an AWS IoT SQL query that triggers a Lambda function, but the "state" remains empty in the Lambda event.

Below is a snippet of my Lambda function code:

python

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   state = event.get("state")
```

The data I'm sending to the topic
$aws/things/<THING_NAME>/shadow/name/<SHADOW_NAME>/update/accepted has the following format:

```
{
  "state": {
    "reported": {
      "access_points": [
        {
          "SSID": "SSID",
          "Strength": 100,
          "WPAFlags": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Strangely, if I remove the list [] type from the access_points and publish the data, it triggers the Lambda function successfully. However, when the access_points list is included, the Lambda function is not triggered.

Below payload works fine. However I need to send a list.

```
{
  "state": {
    "reported": {
      "access_points": 
        {
          "SSID": "SSID",
          "Strength": 100,
          "WPAFlags": 0
        }
      
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the following SQL query in AWS IoT Core:

```
SELECT state.reported as state, topic() as topic FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/name/+/update/accepted'
```

Could there be an issue with the query? Is it not supported to use a JSON array type (access_points) in the reported state? Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.